# What does "color ordering" mean when used with distorted inputs with inception model

Tags: tensorflow, image-preprocessing, data-augmentation

I have been looking for pre-processing techniques of input images. After looking into the implementation of the inception model at: https://github.com/awslabs/deeplearning-benchmark/blob/master/tensorflow/inception/inception/image_processing.py#L164, I found that they have used `color_ordering` parameter which could be 0 or 1. What does color ordering mean in this context?